# Debug iOS App Share Extension with Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I am just starting out with iOS App Share Extension and dutifully followed the instructions for Xcode 8.1 to create a new target. Great, it gave me some simple boilerplate code and a scheme. I then put some breakpoints on the code view that was generated and tried to run the extension target.

It asks me for an app. Hm, I didn't see Contacts, so chose my app instead.
My app appears in the simulator.
I close (home) my app and start Contacts.
I go to share a contact and my extension shows!!!
I tap it and a generic dialog appears.

But nothing shows up in my debugger or in my log from print.

What switch am I missing?

Comment: When I am debugging extension I launch my main app as usual and then from within Xcode choose attache to process by pid or name and type in the name of the extension

Comment: That was the answer. Thank you, I was really struggling with this all day yesterday.